# Is there a better way to tell "s/he"?

Tags: expressions

For example:

> Ask a grammatist, she or he will possibly know how to solve this question!

Is it possible to replace the `she or he` part with a single word - probably something not gender dependent - in this kind of sentences?

Comment: I often see _they_ used

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: @Josh61 Ohh, I see, so it is applicable to a single person too... Thanks!